# CSS only menu popout?

Tags: css, menu

I'd like to have a logo (say it's square for simplicity) with 4 links that pop up when it is moused over. These would be positioned Above, Below and to the sides of the menu/logo.

Is this achievable with only CSS? Any suggestions for how one might go about doing it?

Semantically I'd like to order them with in the page something like:

```
<ul><li><a href="Homepage">Logo</a>
    <ul><li class="north"><a href="north">North</a></li>
        <li class="west"><a href="west">West</a></li>
        <li class="east"><a href="east">East</a></li>
        <li class="south"><a href="south">South</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But have them show up on the page like:

```
             North
       West  Logo   East
             South
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

### HTML

```
<ul><li><a href="Homepage">Logo</a>
    <ul id="map"><li class="north"><a href="north">North</a></li>
        <li class="west"><a href="west">West</a></li>
        <li class="east"><a href="east">East</a></li>
        <li class="south"><a href="south">South</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
#map li a {
    display: none;
}

#map li:hover a {
    display: block;
}
```

Note that IE6 won't fire the `:hover` pseudo class on anything but links (you might want to change your markup).

Also simply use absolute positioning to position the popups.

See the general idea [here](http://jsbin.com/ojogi3/edit).

Comment: Frankly, I don't give a damn about IE6. I've got to make some stuff I do at work look at least halfway decent in it at work, but I'm not going to pay the slightest bit of attention to it for my personal projects.
Anyways, thanks, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @aslum It's a start, but it should give you the general idea. Once you've got it working with CSS only, you can add some pretty JavaScript stuff too (like animations).